# javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error: ssl=0x56e63588: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer

Tags: java, android, ssl, sslexception

I have been using using `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` to download some data from a HTTP server for past 2 years and its been working fine.

Recently we switched to HTTPS for some security reasons.This is also working fine with WiFi and High speed mobile data(3G).But most often with slow data connection(2G) My download interrupted with following stack trace.

```
 javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error: ssl=0x56e63588: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:690)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:103)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.read(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:120)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:131)
    at org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream.read(EofSensorInputStream.java:140)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:114)
```

This is how my Code Looks like :

```
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                UrlEncodedFormEntity p_entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                        params, HTTP.UTF_8);
                httpPost.setEntity(p_entity);
                response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                DataInputStream in = new               DataInputStream(response.getEntity().getContent());
                String st = "";
                result = new Vector<String>();
                while ((st = readLine(in)) != null) {
                result.addElement(st);
         }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 package com.telpoo.frame.net;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import org.apache.http.HttpVersion;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpProtocolParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;

public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        super(truststore);

        TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        };

        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
    }

    public static  HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
        try {
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            trustStore.load(null, null);

            SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
            sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

            SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
            registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
            registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

            ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

            return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new DefaultHttpClient();
        }
    }

}
```

and use it:

```
URL myUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpClient client = MySSLSocketFactory.getNewHttpClient(); // myHttpClient();

            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), connectTimeout);

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(myUrl.toURI());
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. But I'm not using KeyStore  anywhere ! Is it mandatory to to use that while hitting HTTPS page ?

Comment: I have tried this solution but still I'm getting the same error ! but not often as earlier !

Comment: How did you fix this? I'm having a similar issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30475191/javax-net-ssl-sslexception-read-error-ssl-0x9a602800-i-o-error-during-system